# mysql returning only one result instead of multiple

Tags: mysql

I have an sql table that has multiple ids for a given criteria:

```
mysql> select distinct id from FILTER where ft='f' and timestamp between '1367539200000' and '1367625599999';
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 0   |
| 121 |
| 122 |
| 124 |
| 125 |
| 127 |
+-----+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I want to run a query that will give results for all 6 rows:

```
mysql> select a.id, count(a.id) as total, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS allowed, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS modified, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blocked from FILTER a INNER JOIN EVENTS b on a.fid = b.event_id and a.timestamp = b.timestamp where b.protocol_type='MM4' and a.ft='f' and a.id in ('0', '121', '122', '124', '125', '127') and a.fid=b.event_id and b.timestamp between '1367539200000' and '1367625599999';
+----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | total | allowed | modified | blocked |
+----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
| 0  |   216 |       0 |      135 |      81 |
+----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

This only returns the first row. I can verify that one of the other ids fulfuls the filter criteria (in fact they all do):

```
mysql> select a.id, count(a.id) as total, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS allowed, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS modified, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blocked from FILTER a INNER JOIN EVENTS b on a.fid = b.event_id and a.timestamp = b.timestamp where b.protocol_type='MM4' and a.ft='f' and a.id='127' and a.fid=b.event_id and b.timestamp between '1367539200000' and '1367625599999';
+-----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
| id  | total | allowed | modified | blocked |
+-----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
| 127 |    24 |       0 |       15 |       9 |
+-----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I also tried without the in-list:

```
mysql> select a.id, count(a.id) as total, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS allowed,  SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS modified, SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blocked from FILTER a INNER JOIN EVENTS b on a.fid = b.event_id and a.timestamp = b.timestamp where b.protocol_type='MM4' and a.ft='f' and a.fid=b.event_id and b.timestamp between '1367539200000' and '1367625599999';
+----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | total | allowed | modified | blocked |
+----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
| 0  |   216 |       0 |      135 |      81 |
+----+-------+---------+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

How can I change my filter to show 6 rows for each id rather than just the first row?

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` and `sum` are both aggregation functions. With a `group by` clause you can group by `id` (unique) and show all.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing all of your table structures, but try putting a `GROUP BY` at the end of your query:

```
... your query as posted, with ...
GROUP BY a.id
```

Without the `GROUP BY` you're instructing MySQL to give you grand totals rather than totals by ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, 
count(a.id) as total, 
SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS allowed, 
SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS modified, 
SUM(CASE WHEN b.result='2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blocked 
from FILTER a INNER JOIN EVENTS b on a.fid = b.event_id and a.timestamp = b.timestamp 
where b.protocol_type = 'MM4' 
and a.ft = 'f' 
and a.fid = b.event_id 
and b.timestamp between '1367539200000' and '1367625599999'
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select 
    a.id, 
    count(a.id) as total, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN b.result='0' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS allowed, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN b.result='1' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS modified, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN b.result='2' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS blocked 
from FILTER a 
    INNER JOIN EVENTS b on a.fid = b.event_id 
        and a.timestamp = b.timestamp 
where b.protocol_type='MM4' 
    and a.ft='f' 
    and a.id='127' 
    and a.fid=b.event_id 
    and b.timestamp between '1367539200000' and '1367625599999'
group by a.id;
```